# Binding function to $interval

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a service that I'm using to manage the state, like the time since a user last did something.  In another directive, I use the interval service to check this state (lastActivity), but it's not getting updated:

// myservice

```
    start() {
        this.$document.on(this.DOMevents, this.updateActivity);
    }
    
    stop() {
        this.$document.off(this.DOMevents, this.updateActivity)
    }
    
    updateActivity() {
        this.lastActivity = new Date();
    }
```

// other directive

```
           $interval(() => {
              
               console.log(myservice.lastActivity.getTime()); // lastActivity is just a javascript Date
               
               }
           }, 1000);
```

I think this is the closure problem in that $interval gets myservice before it runs every 1000 ms so the time is always the same.  Is there a way to pass that in to get updated?  I see in the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval
that there is a pass option as the last parameter, but since I'm using TypeScript and an older version of Angular, I won't be able to use this feature.  Is there another way to do this?

Maybe this explains my problem clearer:

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
                  $interval(() => {
                      console.log(now);
                  }, 1000);
```

I have some service that is keeping track of time amongst other things.  In another directive, after a certain amount of time has passed I want to check this value and do some logic.  Problem is, `now` is always the same time.  So in `myservice`, the `lastActivity` time is not getting read properly in the $interval function.

Comment: your question isn't exactly clear.  the `[Pass]` you have mentioned is referred to as "additional parameters to the executed function.".  I'm not sure what using Typescript and/or an older version of angular has to do with being able to pass additional parameters.  Also, without seeing what the `.getTime()` function does, it's not clear what you would be getting in this `console.log` command, or even what you are expecting to get.

Comment: @Claies lastActivity is just a javascript date so I'm just calling getTime() on it.  myservice tracks the user's lastActivity as a javascript date.  it has some other functionality too, but i left it out of the example.

Comment: In addition to what @Claies has mentioned, services in Angular are singletons so the fact that `$interval` does or does not get a reference to `myservice` before running should be immaterial.

Comment: you haven't provided a lot to go on here.  If `lastActivity` is being updated with a new time, then this function should be outputting the new time.  Services are singletons, so unless you are referring to a different service, this should be working as written.  Seeing more code to understand if anything else is changing the conditions here is necessary.

Comment: @Claies Ok I tried updating it more to make it clearer.

Comment: well according to that code, you never change the `now` to a new value...

Comment: @Claies ah you are right on that one, but in myservice, the lastActivity value is changed. So i guess that was a bad example.  Trying to think of a better one...

Comment: Ah...it looks like you are using a getter/setter in your service to return `lastActivity` which would cause the behavior you're seeing.